# How can I convert array to dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe:

| ID |
| --- |
| 239200202 |
| 14700993 |
| 1153709258720067584 |

And have a output whether the id is a bot or not in an array form [1,1,0]
How can I combine it into one dataframe like:

| ID | Bot |
| --- | --- |
| 239200202 | bot |
| 14700993 | bot |
| 1153709258720067584 | Not bot |

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
test = pd.read_csv('./user_data/user_lookup/dataset/test_dataframe.csv', index_col=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['UserID','Bot/Not'])
for index,row in test.iterrows():
   if test[index] == 1:
      df.loc[index,['UserID']] = test['User ID']
      df.loc[index,['Bot/Not']] = 'Bot'
   if test[index] == 0:
      df.loc[index, ['UserID']] = test['User ID']
      df.loc[index, ['Bot/Not']] = 'Not-Bot'
print(df)
```

It would be great if someone can help me out.
Thank you

Comment: is `test_dataframe.csv` contains ID only?

Comment: what is the name of the array?

Comment: yes test_dataframe.csv only has ids. I dropped the rest of the columns because I don't need it.

Comment: array is an output from: pred_logreg_test = logreg.predict(test_scaled) I am predicting the output array whether the id is a bot or not

Comment: you can use pandas [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas-dataframe-assign), for you array/list you can do a list comprehension `arr =[1,1,0]`  `arr = ['Bot' if x==1 else 'Not-Bot' for x in arr]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the hints that you have given in the question,

You can add the column name `Bot` to the test dataframe as follow:

```py
new_pred = ['bot' if x==1 else 'Not bot' for x in pred_logreg_test]
test['Bot'] = list(new_pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to the above problem

```
array = [1,1,0]
df['BOT']=df.loc[df['ID'].isin(array)]
```

Answer (score 1):

it's best to use here with pd.concat , to merge this 2 df into one

also, try to avoid iterrows at any cost while working with DataFrames, its substantially slower

example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [100, 101, 102]})
bot_not_bot = np.array([1,0,1])
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'bot/not bot': bot_not_bot})], axis=1)
```

instead of using iterrows which is slower, use apply for faster results on larger scale DataFrames

```
df['bot/not bot'] = df['bot/not bot'].apply(lambda x: 'Bot' if x else 'Not Bot')
```

This is the correct way to use Dataframes, avoid iterrows

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing into an array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UserID': [239200202, 14700993, 1153709258720067584]})
is_bot = np.array([1,1,0])
df['Bot'] = np.array(['not bot', 'bot'])[is_bot]
```